# Симулятор для ATiny2313 в Atmel Studio 7

Tags: avr, atmel-studio

Как добраться до симулятора AVR, а именно ATiny2331 в Atmel Studio 7, и есть ли он там? Самое главное - пошаговая отладка и присмотр за регистрами и лапками портов. Можно и без создания какой либо обвязки. Proteus'ом пользоваться не умею.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Atmel Studio 7 есть симулятор для всех выпускаемых микроконтроллеров AVR. Чтобы при отладке проекта выбрать симулятор, нужно в свойствах проекта (ALT+F7) во вкладке "Tools" выбрать "Simulator" и сохраниться. После этих действий отладка будет проходить в симуляторе.